# Why is Android studio complaining about OpenJDK?

Tags: java, android, manjaro, jdk

I have latest version of Manjaro 64 bit, latest version of Oracle's JDk and Latest version of Android studio. Everything is up to date on my system.

- Android studio is complaining about OpenJDK

[image]

- Although I have Oracle's JDK, not OpenJDK

[image]

- And it's configured correctly

[image]

Why?

Comment: What is the output of `java -version`?

Comment: @mjturner you're right wasn't set as default, had to do `sudo archlinux-java set java-8-jdk` kinda strange but seems it happens. Thanks

Comment: No problem. I'll add that as a suggested answer then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that your default JDK is the Oracle JDK and not OpenJDK. Many distributions ship with OpenJDK by default due to licensing issues and even if you install the Oracle JDK it might not then be the default. Running `java -version` from a terminal should tell you which is the default.